# Adding JAR to CLASSPATH in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I am trying to set up the CLASSPATH for Java under Mac OS.

Specifically I am trying to add a couple of JAR archives to it.

If I do it like:

```
## Setting up ASM bytecode instructor library
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/fork/Dev/ASM/lib/all/asm-all-3.3.1.jar
```

It works fine. However, if I set it like the documentation recommends:

```
## Setting up ASM bytecode instructor library
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/fork/Dev/ASM/lib/all/*
```

It does not seem to work.

The thing is that I want to add, let's say 10 jars, it sounds impractical to add one-by-one.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What documentation shows the *?

Comment: Here http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html Look for the wildcard section.

Comment: Perhaps the classpath wildcard handling and the shell wildcard expansion are getting in each others way. Try escaping the asterisk, like `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/fork/Dev/ASM/lib/all/'*'`

Comment: No error, it simply won't find the Jar, and another project I have will not build, because it can not find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set the jars on the classpath individually. 
There are ways around this though. One that I use is starting the java app with a shell script that contains something like this:

```
 cd $JAR_DIR
 jars=($(ls *.jar))
 JAR_PATH=""
 dir=$(pwd)
 for i in "${jars[@]}"; do
    JAR_PATH="${JAR_PATH}:$dir/$i"
 done
 CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAR_PATH
```

This will work.

Comment: This isn't correct for Java 6; you can wildcard jar files onto the classpath just fine.