# Java on the Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos

I've been programming Java on windows for ages and just moved to the Mac.

I'm running the following command which works on the PC but doesn't on a Mac what am I doing wrong.

```
java -classpath ./lib.patches/*:./lib.core/*:./lib.custom/* test.Test
```

This gives me a ClassNotFound but test.Test is in a one of the jars in the path.

Thanks for all help.

OK I've debugged further and when I run this command

```
java -cp . test.Test
```

I've worked it out!!

The script was copied from a PC and had the wrong returns to end the lines.

This had the bizarre outcome of creating a ClassNotFound.

from the command line it works but from a script it throws ClassNotFound - must be a Mac issue ...

Comment: java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)

Comment: Why are you escaping the `*`s?

Comment: @Inerdia It'll glob if you don't.

Comment: @Dan Where's the `test.Test` class? It works fine for me.

Comment: @Inerdia (Sorry, that's Linux, not OSX, they don't need to be escaped.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding JAR to CLASSPATH in Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028286/adding-jar-to-classpath-in-mac-os)

Comment: The duplicate I've attached (above comment) says that wildcarding doesn't work on Mac OS X. A quick look on Google yielded another claim that this was not added to Apple's JDK.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Not really, since wildcarding works fine for me on Java 6.

Comment: see my further debugging above - maybe I should raise that as a new question?

Comment: @Dan Did you try defining the `java` command's classpath including the current directory? You should, if `test.Test` is in class files off the current directory. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifying @Dave Newton's result, using

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
```

with [`ThermometerDemo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597015/changing-mercury-color-in-thermometer-in-jfreechart/7602126#7602126), this command works:

```
$ java -cp /opt/jfreechart/*:build/classes chart.ThermometerDemo
```

Comment: The [wildcard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) is new in J2SE 6; cf [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/classpath.html).

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me. (Escaping to show it's not related to shell globbing, but it works either way.)

With lucene-core in directory 1 and lucene demo in directory 2, or both in a single directory:

```
...lucene/lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ echo $CLASSPATH

...lucene/lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ java -cp ./1/\*:./2/\* org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs .
Indexing to directory 'index'...
adding ./1/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar
adding ./2/lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
adding ./index/_0.fdt
adding ./index/_0.fdx
adding ./index/write.lock
1605 total milliseconds
```

If you also need class files based off the current directory, you should explicitly add the `.` path to the classpath.

Comment: +1 I get a similar [result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907814/java-on-the-mac/7908432#7908432).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
java -cp './lib.patches/*:./lib.core/*:./lib.custom/*' test.Test
```

instead

Comment: does Test.java have "package test;" at the top?